# Git: How to see unpushed commits (or all commits) in your local branch is you do not have a set upstream?

Tags: git, github

I have branched off a release branch to my own feature branch.

I've done the work and now I want to set and push it upstream but it says some of my commits do not have the right regex to start them off, but I double checked and they do.

When I use "git log" I see there are some other people's commits on my local branch? (Not sure if git log is supposed to show that or not)

So my question is - how do I show all my local commits that have not yet been pushed if I do not have a set upstream yet (since I can't set it because of the regex issue).

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: the regex is what tries to match against your commit messages; the commit messages themselves are presumably ordinary strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have branched off a release branch to my own feature branch.

  OK: good
- I've done the work and now I want to set and push it upstream but it says some of my commits do not have the right regex.

  Please [Edit] your post and copy/paste the exact error message.

  If possible, please also copy/paste your team's regex for enforcing Git commit messages.  Ask for guidance if you need help.
- When I use "git log" I see there are some other people's commits on my local branch.

  Well yes - you're seeing the cumulative history of everything that occurred - including commits that preceded your creating your own branch
- Q: how do I show all my local commits that have not yet been pushed?

  Your best bet is to check the "push" history on the remote where your parent branch resides (e.g. look at the project history on the GitHub web page, if your organization happens to be using GitHub).